# Installing Debugging Tools for Windows from command line

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmd, uwp, angle

I am trying to automate a Windows build in AWS Codebuild which require downloading Windows SDK with `Debugging Tools for Windows` installed.

I am able to install the Windows SDK using Visual Studio with some other files required.

```
powershell -c "Start-Process -FilePath 'vs_community.exe' -ArgumentList \"--quiet\", 
\"--norestart\" , \"--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal\", 
\"--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop\", 
\"--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC\", 
\"--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041\", 
\"--includeRecommended\" -Wait;"
```

The build requires `Debugging Tools for Windows` enabled in Windows SDK which is straightforward in UI installation. But since I want to automate this, I am looking for a command line option to install `Debugging Tools for Windows` in Windows 10 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install Debugging Tools for Windows via standalone windows sdk installer through command line as below:

```
powershell -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2120843' -OutFile winsdksetup.exe -UseBasicParsing ;"
winsdksetup.exe /features + /q /norestart
```

`/features +` selects all the features available in Windows SDK to install.

Comment: `.\winsdksetup.exe /features OptionId.WindowsDesktopDebuggers /q /norestart` to just install the debugging tools.  You will get a new PowerShell prompt immediately but the installation is happening in the background.  You'll have to poll to test that it was actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `winsdksetup.exe /list` to see all features list. 
For Debugging Tools use: `winsdksetup.exe /features OptionId.WindowsDesktopDebuggers`
You can add `\q` for quiet install, and `/norestart` for no restart after install.

The Windows SDK (winsdksetup.exe) can be found [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)